# Why is curl returning nginx?

Tags: rhel, curl, nginx

I'm on a RHELx64 7.3; I Do Not have nginx installed.

Why is it when I `curl badsite.cooo` I get an nginx response?

```
$ curl badsite.cooo
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

At first I thought maybe that was Google, but that sounds absurd.  Is  that my ISP then, or what?  I have some assumptions; is that my DNS server box?  Also I have lighttpd, and php55w, and fast-cgi, is it one of those?

```
$ curl -v badsite.coooo
* About to connect() to badsite.coooo port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 198.105.254.114...
* Connected to badsite.coooo (198.105.254.114) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: badsite.coooo
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx
< Date: Thu, 02 Feb 2017 09:00:32 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: close
< Location: http://localhost
< Expires: Thu, 02 Feb 2017 09:00:31 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Edit, wait that's me??

```
$ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (74.125.28.101), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  router.ld.pvt (192.168.1.254)  0.866 ms  0.837 ms  0.814 ms
 ...
 ...
```

??

ld.pvt is me, whats `router.`?  Not sure what that subdomain is; I have all kinds of services I've been getting setup here for php, but I still don't recognize the subdomain.

Comment: Some ISPs have a bad habit of showing a special page for domains which they couldn't resolve. Add output of  `curl -v basite.cooo`

Comment: added traceroute

also thought about this, and looks like when i installed the server, i chose bind, makes sense in hindsight, is this bind then though?, `$ which named
/sbin/named`.  Whats this in nmap? `111/tcp  open  rpcbind
` is that it?  
Note, i also thoroughly searched for the response string, as well as nginx configs, they are non existent.

Comment: ok i must be mixed up, sorry, its late, thats my router, and i shoudl have traced to badsite...  ` traceroute badsite.cooo
traceroute to badsite.cooo (198.105.254.114), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets.
`

Answer (score 1):

This is from the Frontier ISP, and it is pretty much search and advertising DNS.  This info was dug from [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/what-should-dns-servers-return-for-localhost-localdomain-4175528941/), particularly this part

> It appears that localhost.localdomain was resolving to 198.105.254.114, some advertising search site that my ISP (frontiernet) was putting in their nameserver and returning for any unresolvable DNS query that resembled a FQDN.

```
$ nslookup localhost.localdomain
Server:         192.168.1.254
Address:        192.168.1.254#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   localhost.localdomain
Address: 198.105.254.114
Name:   localhost.localdomain
Address: 198.105.244.114
```

So if you `curl` a site that has to be searched, it hits the ISP DNS, which in this case is returning a 301 moved permanently, not the most accurate answer, since it never existed in the first place.